# groovy assert statement behaves like a method and not like a statement

Tags: groovy

If I use an assertion for a correct groovy statement and I leave out the parenthesis then 'assert' throws a `MultipleCompilationErrorsException` with an 'unexpected token' message.

`assert` (and at least `if`) seems to behave like a method instead of a statement, since nested function calls don't accept leaving out parenthesis.

So when I have a correct example and I use it as an assertion I get an error. I expect `assert` to accept correct groovy statements if they are correct without an `assert`.

I did not find this problem described in Stackoverflow, Groovy JIRA or via internet search.

```
assert null == println('foo')
```

or

```
println 'foo'
```

both output `foo` (as expected), but

```
assert null == println 'foo'
```

throws

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
script_from_command_line: 1: unexpected token: foo @ line 1, column 24.
   assert null == println 'foo'
                          ^

1 error
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI : `assert` is also a keyword like `return`, `import` and etc.
See the [groovy doc](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-syntax.html).

As we know we can't **ommit the paranthesis** after the keyword such as `return`. See the document [omitting_parentheses](https://groovy-lang.org/style-guide.html#_omitting_parentheses). Unfortunately it only discuss about the method not mentioning any keywords :( .

```
return test("String")  // will work

return test "String" // won't
```

I hope you got the point.

Comment: I suppose you mean "In some cases parentheses are required, such as when making nested method calls or when calling a method without parameters."
This sentence gives some example regarding method calls (but not keywords).I already knew that nested method calls don't support omitting parenthesis.
What puzzled me was that a keyword does not seem to support this. And this was neither explicitly mentioned in the "omitting parenthesis" part of the groovy docs nor in the syntax spec for groovy keywords.
Or did I miss a part of the docs where this is stated about keywords?

Comment: @StefanRother-Stübs. True and agree. There is no correct documentation for these special keywords as they have only enclosed `println` default method. I just tried to mention the behavior of `assert` also matches with other keywords such as `return` for which we are ok with the behavior (can't omit parenthesis for nested case like method). `assert` is not alone. : )